# Is there a default date for instantiation in Java?

Tags: java, date, instantiation

For example, when instantiating an int you might say:

```
int num = 0;
```

Is there something you can use like 0 for a Date?

Answer (score 5):

Code

```
Date date= new Date(0);
System.out.println(date);
```

Output

```
Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970
```

Comment: I think this misses the crucial point here - the OP [shouldn't need to do this at all](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20702301/474189).

Comment: @Duncan I'm not sure what your point is. The confusing issue is that Java mixes the use of objects ([OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)) with [primitives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) (non-OOP). Objects must be instantiated whereas primitives can have default values. Ideally Java would have had only objects, but at the time of its creation the marketplace refused to accept any new language without C-like syntax and primitives.

Comment: @basil Objects have a default value of `null`. I don't think one has to treat primitives or objects any differently.

Answer (score 2):

`Date` is an `Object`. you can not assign `0`. You can use

```
  Date date=null;
```

Or

```
 Date date =new Date();
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you create objects at the moment in your code when you need them. You should never have to create a variable or field containing a default value.

For instance, I would never expect to see `int foo = 0;` in Java code, except when `foo` ought to hold the value zero, e.g. at the start of some loop construct.

If you are asking this question then you possibly misunderstand how variables or fields should be used in Java. If you wish to indicate your field is not yet assigned, then assign no value and leave the variable/field as `null`. E.g.

```
private Date orderDate;

public void someMethod() {
  if (orderDate != null) {
    // Do some stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All three Java date-time frameworks default new instances to the current date-time in the default time zone.

- [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)/[Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) (no-arg constructor)
- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (no-arg constructor)
- java.time.* [JSR 310: Date and Time API](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) (static [`now()`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) factory methods)

Comment: Hm, I have not seen any constructors in JSR-310, at least not in classes like ZonedDateTime, LocalDateTime, LocalDate or LocalTime.

Comment: @MenoHochschild I stand corrected; the JSR 310 classes use static factory methods ([`.now()`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html)) rather than no-arg constructors. I rewrote my answer accordingly.